# Wolfson audio card not working after rpi-update

Tags: raspbian, linux, wolfson-audio-card

Just used rpi-update to update the Pi and things went bad. Previously, was using the base Raspbian image with Wolfson drivers and that worked well. Suddenly, nothing. Alsamixer doesn't show anything. So, used rpi-update to revert to a previous commit and still same issue. Any ideas? Thanks.

Update : Used an older base build in a spare card that worked on the minimal. Then did apt-get update. Still working. Apt-get upgrade and that is where the Wolfson drivers disappear. Will update when I get back to work and try it out further.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfson drivers do not work with the latest kernel, so doing an rpi-update will cause the problems you're seeing.

http://www.element14.com/community/thread/37006/l/update-on-up-streaming-audiocard-drivers-to-the-312-raspberry-pi-kernel